# getting "Your connection is not private" after setting tls in kubernetes ingress

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, kubernetes-ingress

I'm still getting this privacy error
I'm still getting this privacy error
[image]

the `issuer` generate a certificate and all things is good

[image]

this is the ingress yaml:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minimal-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-nginx
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "myhost.com"
      secretName: letsencrypt-nginx
  rules:
  - host: myhost.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:  
              name: backend-service
              port:
                number: 3000
```

what could be the problem ?!

Comment: The issuer must be in the same namespace as your ingress. Are all your resources under the `default` namespace?

Comment: yes i make sure that all of them under the same namespace which is default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you are using [cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/docs/) to generate CA signed certificates. The certificate status appears to be `True` which means cert-manager has successfully provisioned the certificate.

From the naming convention, I'm assuming your are using letsencrypt as `Issuer`.

However the browser is still throwing Certificate warning. This happens when you use the staging letsencrypt API endpoint, i.e. `https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory`

Cert-manager has [documented](https://cert-manager.io/docs/tutorials/acme/dns-validation/#:%7E:text=We%20have%20specified,org/directory.) this too.

The staging API endpoint is there for you to [experiment around and gain confidence](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/staging-environment/#continuous-integration-development-testing) before using the production API endpoint, i.e. `https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory in your` in your `Issuer` spec.

Staging LetsEncrypt API endpoint has same rate limits as the Production LetsEncrypt API endpoint with few [exceptions](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/staging-environment/#rate-limits).

Consider using Production LetsEncrypt API endpoint in your `Issuer` to avoid certificate related warnings.